# Install and run node module - step by step (EventDrops)

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I guess this must be super-easy, but I'm kind of lost right now. All I want to do is to run the [demo application](https://marmelab.com/EventDrops/) from EventDrops on my local server. The Github project have a [demo folder](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops/tree/master/demo) which I try to run on my server.

The steps I took:

1. Install a fresh Linux Mint Mate: Check.
2. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade: Check.
3. apt-get install build-essentials: Check
4. apt-get install nodejs
5. apt-get install npm

Alright. On the [Github page](https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops) is stated that I could use npm to install EventDrops.

```
npm install event-drops --save
```

This works, at least I don't get any error messages. What must I do now to run the demo? I want to include my own JSON file with my own data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start up an HTTP server and serve the demo directory.

You can use something like [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) to simply serve the demo directory, this is probably the quickest way to get things up and running. But you might want to look into [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) if you will need to build on top of the web framework and serve non-static content.